# I'd like to port simple C++ echo server to C#

Tags: c#, c++, networking, sockets

```
SOCKET  client  = accept(listen_sock, 0, 0);

timeval client_to;
client_to.tv_sec    = 1;
client_to.tv_usec   = 0;
setsockopt(client, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, (char*)&client_to, sizeof(client_to));
char    buffer[1024];
while ((ret = recv(client, buffer, 1024, 0)) != 0)
{
    cout    << "<in loop>" << endl;
    if (ret == -1 && WSAGetLastError() != WSAETIMEDOUT) break;
    if (ret > 0)    cout    << std::string(buffer, 0, ret) << endl;
}

closesocket(client);
```

Above code is a part of simple echo server written in C++.
The problems what I'm facing are...

1. How to set timeout value and detect timeout time is expired?
2. How to detect disconnection of the socket?

Please let me show some code in C#. Thanks.

added >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>

Part of my C# code is follow...

```
try
{
    // Read all
    spider.Client.ReceiveTimeout = 500; // spider is TcpClient type and blocking socket.
    int readCount = 0;
    SocketError socketError;
    while ((readCount = spider.Client.Receive(tempBuffer, 0, tempBuffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, out socketError)) > 0) // I  think time-out does not work, Receive() returns immediately.
    {
    recvBuffer.Append(tempBuffer, 0, readCount);
    }
}
catch (Exception e) // even though spider is disconnect, no exception occurred. how can I detect disconnection?
{
    Console.WriteLine("Exception: {0}", e.Message);

}
```

Comment: So your question is more "write this for me" than "please help write this"? :) I would suggest giving it a try and coming back when you face actual C# related problems. .NET got a Socket class that works very much like any other socket, except that it is a class and not functions and a handle.

Comment: Does my article seem insincere? I've tested many times using C# and could not find the right way. I'm not just asking without doing nothing. I know C#'s socket is similar(I hope really) but it's not easy make it to work as I expected. Thanks anyway.

Comment: No problem, but could you post your current C# code so we could work with that? It makes it easier for everybody, as it is now you seem to have two different questions, maybe it would be better to split them up in two different questions.

Answer (score 0):

Check out **[XF.Server](http://www.kodart.com/download/)** socket library by **[kodart](http://www.kodart.com/)** for .net. When you download the library it comes with an echo server as example implementation of Xf.Server library. This will work for you.

www.kodart.com

Thanks.